# Tensorflow's ResNet on custom image data

Tags: tensorflow, resnet

I'm trying to run Tensorflow's [ResNet implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet) on a custom image dataset I have. I have no prior experience with Tensorflow and neural/conv nets, so this has been a learning experience for me as well.

There are two examples of the implementation, one for the CIFAR10 dataset and another for the ImageNet dataset. I chose to use CIFAR10's example as a baseline because it seemed easier to get started and I was already familiar with the CIFAR10 dataset. I ran it on the CIFAR10 dataset following the README file available and managed to switch the data and run it for my own dataset of 32x32 images with relative ease.

The problem is, my original dataset contains 512x512 images and I'd like to run it with this original size. I converted the dataset into cifar10's binary format (maintaining the 512x512 size) and adapted the implementation to try to run it. Namely, I changed the file paths and file names and changed the size constants to reflect the dataset:

```
_HEIGHT = 512
_WIDTH = 512
_NUM_CHANNELS = 3
_DEFAULT_IMAGE_BYTES = _HEIGHT * _WIDTH * _NUM_CHANNELS
_RECORD_BYTES = _DEFAULT_IMAGE_BYTES + 1
_NUM_CLASSES = 5
_NUM_DATA_FILES = 10

_NUM_IMAGES = {
    'train': 1000,
    'validation': 200,
}
```

However, when I try to run a few problems appear. If I try to run it as is, I get the bad memory alloc error below:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

My dataset contains more than 1200 images, but if I try to use them all at once my computer runs out of memory and crashes (I'm currently setting up a more resourceful computer to address this issue). Because of this, I was wondering if this still meant that I didn't have enough memory to run the code with the 512x512 images. I saw that tensorflow uses the batch_size parameter to decide on how many images to buffer

```
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)
```

so I tried reducing the batch size as well, to see if it was a problem in allocating memory for the image buffer. The same error occurs until I get as low as a batch of 16 images. For 8 images, however, this problem no longer appears and instead I get a different error message:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path-to/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
  File "path-to/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1312, in _run_fn
options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "path-to/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1420, in _call_tf_sessionrun
status, run_metadata)
  File "path-to/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[117128,5] labels_size=[8,5]
 [[Node: softmax_cross_entropy_loss/xentropy = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](softmax_cross_entropy_loss/xentropy/Reshape, softmax_cross_entropy_loss/xentropy/Reshape_1)]]
```

It seems that there is a mismatch between the dataset size and the labels array, but that problem appears only when I try running it on 512x512 images, it works for any batch size on 32x32 images.

**Finally, my question is,** is there some other parameter I have to change or other adaptation I have to make to run the ResNet CIFAR10 code on my 512x512 dataset? Are these errors somehow related to something I'm doing wrong or there are likely two things I have to address? Any insight on what is causing these errors would be of great help as well.

**Put briefly, what changes would I have to make to input my own 512x512 dataset into TensorFlow's ResNet CIFAR10 implementation?**

This is my first question at StackOverflow and as I said I'm new to many things in the field of the question, so please, forgive any rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, there were two different problems with the code.

First, the machine did not have enough memory to run the code because of the size of the network and the images. One workaround was to use a machine with more memory, that worked and fixed the first problem. However, since increasing memory is not always an option, I later found out that I could decrease the memory consumption by increasing the size or stride of the first convolutional layer. This is particularly useful for running ResNet on GPUs, which are often constrained by memory.

Second, there was a mismatch between the size of the network's output and the size of my labels vector (the expected size). That happened because of the change in the input size. The network downsamples the input through its convlutional and pooling layers. The problem was that the network was not downsampling the input enough for the expected output size. Changing the layers sizes in the networks hyperparameters addressed this issue.

To answer the brief question, to run the code on a custom dataset I had to change the variables in the question (_HEIGHT, _WIDTH, etc.) and the size of the layers in the model definition in the code.